# Deleting multiple rows from Kendo grid makes the page become unresponsive

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a grid with checkbox for every row, I tried `grid.removeRow`, `dataSource.remove(item)`, `splice()` everything does not work for me.

The grid just consists of 4 columns included checkbox, and the records are just around 1.6k. The page just become unresponsive when I click the delete button to delete based of the checkbox of each row.

Here is my code:

```js
var raw = $scope.DataSource.data();
var length = raw.length;
var item, i;
for (i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     item = raw[i];
     if(!item.IsSelect) //IsSelect here is the boolean variable
        $scope.DataSource.remove(item);
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: My guess is the view is trying to render the grid again every time a record is removed. Therefore the page will become unresponsive, because it's busy rendering the grid 1600 times! But without more details/code/jsfiddle we can't say a lot about the problem

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the items outside a for loop. There is probably some redrawing after each removal, thus freezing the browser

Answer (score 0):

Well, i also have done same thing, and i must say the Kendo Grid for Angular 2 is really poor performance wise. 
Also, i did that with angular 2 grid, cant say that it will help you with Angular1.

Edit: i am using splice to remove selected row data from Grid:

```
this.array1.push(this.checkedArrayData[i]);
this.array2.splice(this.checkedArrayData[i], 1);
```

//reassigns the array datasource to grid

```
this.array2 = this.array2.slice();
```